# PHP mail sends to junk folder

Tags: php, email, smtp

I know the internet is flooded with this question, but i couldnt find a solution that matches my situation. So, here we go. The site im hosting through allows you to create an email address using your free subdomain, i have done this and chose the option to set as a FROM email. I edited my existing mail() script to have its headers removed, which contained my own FROM email. Now the mail sends using the subdomain email ive created, which is great.. but its still coming out as junk. The help desk said to switch the port the mail sends on to 581, since this will effectively bypass their mail spam filter, so there was no chance of it being tagged before it left their server. I dont have access to the actual php.ini file, but i have used this:

```
ini_set('smtp_port', '587');
```

And currently, my test mail script looks like this:

```
<?php
ini_set('smtp_port', '587');

$email = 'radicolabs@hotmail.com';
$message = 'Hello.. test message';
$subject = 'You have captured a new IP';

mail($email, $subject, $message);

echo 'mail sent';
?>
```

Comment: You need to add proper [**headers**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). 9 times out of 10 is the reason why.

Comment: Which headers would i need ?

Comment: There is many, many, many brain aching causes for this, that being said.. Mail is possibly one of the hardest things to debug.. It's possibly as @Fred-ii- has mentioned, but if not.. It can be a number of things

Comment: @amartin94 I included a link in my initial comment. Also look up PHPmailer.

Comment: Yeah i spent a while looking over the mail() manual.. what sort of headers would i want to incorporate ?

Comment: @amartin94 [**See example #2 here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) it's a good start which is what I mostly use with success.

Comment: Yeah man, still came out as junk.. looking at the PHPmailer class now

Comment: @amartin94 Did you use your own email address as the `From:` or a bogus email ? It makes a difference.

Comment: I used the email that i created using the free subdomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the email providers considered some emails to be spam so they put it on the junk folder. Did you try the class (**class.phpmailer.php**)?. You can try this link as your reference http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/email/send-email-from-a-page/using-phpmailer-to-send-mail-through-php. Hope it helps.

Comment: `Rest assure this will work and it will definitely go to the inbox`: 1k bet that's not a guarantee. Life is not that easy. You need to take a lot more pains to make sure most of your emails inbox. DKIM, Domain Keys, SPF, Reverse DNS and so on.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes that true but i never said the email go to the inbox a 100%.

Comment: `Rest assure this will work and it will definitely go to the inbox`